# Calculating drain current with series N-channel MOSFETs

Tags: mosfet, analog

When two N-channel MOSFETS are connected in series, with common gate connections, then how can I analyze this circuit to determine Id through these MOSFETS, as a function of Vgs and Vds?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTC21D.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Is there a load between M5 and M6? If so show it.

Comment: Really good question.I was thinking of doing this as a way to make things more idiot proof but Vgs  th     spreads made me not take this any further

Comment: Easy. Total obliteration! Poor transistors. They won't survive.

Answer (score 0):

\$V_{gs}(M5) = V_{gs}(M6)-V_{ds}(M6)\$

If \$M6\$ is in saturation, \$V_{ds}(M6) > V_{gs}(M6)\$.

So what mode are \$M6\$ and \$M5\$ in?

Comment: have to analyze for all possible modes in which both transistor can operate

Comment: You should clarify what you mean by the schematic being mistaken. What are you assuming is the correct schematic?

Comment: The schematic has since been corrected.

Comment: Why do you want the Mosfets to short the power supply? There are better ways to make smoke.